# Create random unit vector inside a defined conical region

Tags: matlab, vector, linear-algebra

I'm looking for a simple way for creating a random unit vector constrained by a conical region. The origin is always the [0,0,0].

My solution up to now:

```
function v = GetRandomVectorInsideCone(coneDir,coneAngleDegree)

coneDir = normc(coneDir);

ang = coneAngleDegree + 1;
while ang > coneAngleDegree
    v = [randn(1); randn(1); randn(1)];
    v = v + coneDir;
    v = normc(v);
    ang = atan2(norm(cross(v,coneDir)), dot(v,coneDir))*180/pi;
end
```

My code loops until the random generated unit vector is inside the defined cone. **Is there a better way to do that?**

Resultant image from test code bellow
[image: Resultant vectors plot]

Resultant frequency distribution using [Ahmed Fasih](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500207/ahmed-fasih) code (in comments).
**I wonder how to get a rectangular or normal distribution.**

```
c = [1;1;1]; angs = arrayfun(@(i) subspace(c, GetRandomVectorInsideCone(c, 30)), 1:1e5) * 180/pi; figure(); hist(angs, 50);
```

[image: Freq angular distribution]

Testing code:

```
clearvars; clc; close all;

coneDir = [randn(1); randn(1); randn(1)];
coneDir = [0 0 1]';
coneDir = normc(coneDir);
coneAngle = 45;
N = 1000;
vAngles = zeros(N,1);
vs = zeros(3,N);
for i=1:N
    vs(:,i) = GetRandomVectorInsideCone(coneDir,coneAngle);
    vAngles(i) = subspace(vs(:,i),coneDir)*180/pi;
end
maxAngle = max(vAngles);
minAngle = min(vAngles);
meanAngle = mean(vAngles);
AngleStd = std(vAngles);

fprintf('v angle\n');
fprintf('Direction: [%.3f %.3f %.3f]^T. Angle: %.2fº\n',coneDir,coneAngle);
fprintf('Min: %.2fº. Max: %.2fº\n',minAngle,maxAngle);
fprintf('Mean: %.2fº\n',meanAngle);
fprintf('Standard Dev: %.2fº\n',AngleStd);

%% Plot
figure;
grid on;
rotate3d on;
axis equal;
axis vis3d;
axis tight;
hold on;
xlabel('X'); ylabel('Y'); zlabel('Z');

% Plot all vectors
p1 = [0 0 0]';
for i=1:N
    p2 = vs(:,i);
    plot3ex(p1,p2);
end

% Trying to plot the limiting cone, but no success here :(
% k = [0 1];
% [X,Y,Z] = cylinder([0 1 0]');
% testsubject = surf(X,Y,Z); 
% set(testsubject,'FaceAlpha',0.5)

% N = 50;
% r = linspace(0, 1, N);
% [X,Y,Z] = cylinder(r, N);
% 
% h = surf(X, Y, Z);
% 
% rotate(h, [1 1 0], 90);
```

plot3ex.m:

```
function p = plot3ex(varargin)

% Plots a line from each p1 to each p2.
% Inputs:
%   p1 3xN
%   p2 3xN
%   args plot3 configuration string
%   NOTE: p1 and p2 number of points can range from 1 to N
%   but if the number of points are different, one must be 1!
% PVB 2016

p1 = varargin{1};
p2 = varargin{2};
extraArgs = varargin(3:end);

N1 = size(p1,2);
N2 = size(p2,2);
N = N1;

if N1 == 1 && N2 > 1
    N = N2;
elseif N1 > 1 && N2 == 1
    N = N1
elseif N1 ~= N2
    error('if size(p1,2) ~= size(p1,2): size(p1,2) and/or size(p1,2) must be 1 !');
end

for i=1:N
    i1 = i;
    i2 = i;

    if i > N1
        i1 = N1;
    end
    if i > N2
        i2 = N2;
    end

    x = [p1(1,i1) p2(1,i2)];
    y = [p1(2,i1) p2(2,i2)];
    z = [p1(3,i1) p2(3,i2)];
    p = plot3(x,y,z,extraArgs{:});
end
```

Comment: The code you give is not really illustrating your question. So let me know if I state your problem right: You have a **_defined_** conical region (known: _origin_, _direction_ and _departure angle_), and you want to generate a random vector (same _origin_) with its direction included in the conical domain ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I've updated the code sample.

Comment: Are there any requirements on the distribution of cosine-angles? I might think the angles should be uniform, but your code produces vectors whose angles with respect to `coneDir` are very skewed.

Comment: Also, note that `subspace(coneDir, -coneDir)` is `0`, so your rejection-sampling code can return points on the opposite side of the sphere as `coneDir`.

Comment: What you mean by "angles with respect to coneDir are very skewed" ?. Fixed the angle calculus, subspace doesn't take into account the vector direction. Now it is ok.

Comment: Try this: `c = [1;1;1]; angs = arrayfun(@(i) subspace(c, GetRandomVectorInsideCone(c, 30)), 1:1e5) * 180/pi; figure(); hist(angs, 50);`. This generates 1e5 points, computes their angle to `c` (your `coneDir`), and plots their histogram. Very few around 0°, with frequencies increasing to 30°. Is this acceptable?

Comment: Oh, nice analysis. I think that is not ok, since I was looking for a normal distribution result.

Comment: Can you update the question describing what statistical properties you’d like the result to have? There’s lots of choices, the problem is very interesting.

Comment: If you want a _normal_ or a _uniform_ distribution of the resulting **angles**, use this as your starting point. Generate `n` random numbers representing your angles (according to the distribution you want). Each number (angle) will define a _circle_ around your cone centerline. Then on each circle generate a random point (or more but then use the same number of points for each circle). All the points obtained will be your vectors (with origin 0), and your distribution should be respected.

Comment: @Hoki, nice! Can you post a code sample as an answer?

Comment: I was about to but I must leave now ... may be later tonight or tomorrow (_if nobody implements it before_).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here’s the solution. It’s based on the wonderful answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/205589/81266. I found this answer by googling “random points on spherical cap”, after I learned on Mathworld that [a spherical cap](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCap.html) is this cut of a 3-sphere with a plane.

Here’s the function:

```
function r = randSphericalCap(coneAngleDegree, coneDir, N, RNG)

if ~exist('coneDir', 'var') || isempty(coneDir)
  coneDir = [0;0;1];
end

if ~exist('N', 'var') || isempty(N)
  N = 1;
end

if ~exist('RNG', 'var') || isempty(RNG)
  RNG = RandStream.getGlobalStream();
end

coneAngle = coneAngleDegree * pi/180;

% Generate points on the spherical cap around the north pole [1].
% [1] See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/205589/81266
z = RNG.rand(1, N) * (1 - cos(coneAngle)) + cos(coneAngle);
phi = RNG.rand(1, N) * 2 * pi;
x = sqrt(1-z.^2).*cos(phi);
y = sqrt(1-z.^2).*sin(phi);

% If the spherical cap is centered around the north pole, we're done.
if all(coneDir(:) == [0;0;1])
  r = [x; y; z];
  return;
end

% Find the rotation axis `u` and rotation angle `rot` [1]
u = normc(cross([0;0;1], normc(coneDir)));
rot = acos(dot(normc(coneDir), [0;0;1]));

% Convert rotation axis and angle to 3x3 rotation matrix [2]
% [2] See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle
crossMatrix = @(x,y,z) [0 -z y; z 0 -x; -y x 0];
R = cos(rot) * eye(3) + sin(rot) * crossMatrix(u(1), u(2), u(3)) + (1-cos(rot))*(u * u');

% Rotate [x; y; z] from north pole to `coneDir`.
r = R * [x; y; z];

end

function y = normc(x)
y = bsxfun(@rdivide, x, sqrt(sum(x.^2)));
end
```

This code *just* implements [joriki’s answer on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/205589/81266), filling in all the details that joriki omitted.

Here’s a script that shows how to use it.

```
clearvars

coneDir = [1;1;1];
coneAngleDegree = 30;
N = 1e4;

sol = randSphericalCap(coneAngleDegree, coneDir, N);
figure;plot3(sol(1,:), sol(2,:), sol(3,:), 'b.', 0,0,0,'rx');
grid
xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z')
legend('random points','origin','location','best')
title('Final random points on spherical cap')
```

Here is a 3D plot of 10'000 points from the 30° spherical cap centered around the `[1; 1; 1]` vector:

[image: 30° spherical cap]

Here’s 120° spherical cap:

[image: 120° spherical cap]

---

Now, if you look at the histogram of the angles between these random points at the `coneDir = [1;1;1]`, you will see that the distribution is skewed. Here’s the distribution:

[image: Histogram of angles between coneDir and vectors on 120° cap]

Code to generate this:

```
normc = @(x) bsxfun(@rdivide, x, sqrt(sum(x.^2)));
mysubspace = @(a,b) real(acos(sum(bsxfun(@times, normc(a), normc(b)))));

angs = arrayfun(@(i) mysubspace(coneDir, sol(:,i)), 1:N) * 180/pi;

nBins = 16;
[n, edges] = histcounts(angs, nBins);
centers = diff(edges(1:2))*[0:(length(n)-1)] + mean(edges(1:2));

figure('color','white');
bar(centers, n);
xlabel('Angle (degrees)')
ylabel('Frequency')
title(sprintf('Histogram of angles between coneDir and random points: %d deg', coneAngleDegree))
```

Well, *this makes sense*! If you generate points from the 120° spherical cap around `coneDir`, **of course** the 1° cap is going to have very few of those samples, whereas the strip between the 10° and 11° caps will have far more points. So what we want to do is normalize the number of points at a given angle by the surface area of the spherical cap at *that* angle.

Here’s a function that gives us the surface area of the spherical cap with radius `R` and angle in radians `theta` (equation 16 on [Mathworld’s spherical cap](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCap.html) article):

```
rThetaToH = @(R, theta) R * (1 - cos(theta));
rThetaToS = @(R, theta) 2 * pi * R * rThetaToH(R, theta);
```

Then, we can normalize the histogram count for each bin (`n` above) by the difference in surface area of the spherical caps at the bin’s edges:

```
figure('color','white');
bar(centers, n ./ diff(rThetaToS(1, edges * pi/180)))
```

The figure:

[image: Normalized histogram]

This tells us “the number of random vectors divided by the surface area of the spherical segment between histogram bin edges”. This is uniform!

(N.B. If you do this normalized histogram for the vectors generated by your original code, using rejection sampling, the same holds: the normalized histogram is uniform. It’s just that rejection sampling is expensive compared to this.)

(N.B. 2: note that the naive way of picking random points on a sphere—by first generating azimuth/elevation angles and then converting these spherical coordinates to Cartesian coordinates—is no good because it bunches points near the poles: [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html), [example](https://www.jasondavies.com/maps/random-points/), [example 2](http://nullprogram.com/sphere-js/?webgl=false). One way to pick points on the entire sphere is sampling from the 3D normal distribution: that way you won’t get bunching near poles. So I believe that your original technique is perfectly appropriate, giving you nice, evenly-distributed points on the sphere without any bunching. This algorithm described above also does the “right thing” and should avoid bunching. Carefully evaluate any proposed algorithms to ensure that the bunching-near-poles problem is avoided.)

Comment: Ohh hey! Nice! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nice. +1 for a good explanation on why generating azimuth/elevation will concentrate points in the poles.

Comment: Added a bugfix (see history) because originally if you asked `coneDir = [0; 0; 1]` (the North Pole), the code breaks and returns all `NaN`s. There may still be numerical issues if `coneDir` is very close to the North Pole, so just avoid those situations. Code is public domain.

Comment: I don't know why but my code does not result in an uniform distribution like yours. So, I'm using your version. Also, can you comment a bit your code?

Comment: @Pedro77 here’s the code with a big docstring: https://github.com/fasiha/personal-matlab-namespace/blob/master/%2Barf/randSphericalCap.m It doesn't have any more inline documentation that the code in the answer but I will fill it out in shortly.

Comment: @Pedro77 also, this answer on Math.StackExchange http://math.stackexchange.com/a/44691/81266 has a really clear description of the algorithm for sampling over the entire sphere. The other answer that I mentioned in the question (http://math.stackexchange.com/a/205589/81266) tells you how to adapt the first algorithm to the cap (rather than the full sphere), and how to rotate it towards `coneDir`, but admittedly that it a little tricky and that part of my code definitely needs more comments. Please stand by.

Comment: @Pedro77 I made a thing: http://bl.ocks.org/fasiha/2bbfc20ef882d76e27f17df31950d156

Answer (score 0):

it is better to use spherical coordinates and convert it to cartesian coordinates:

```
coneDirtheta = rand(1) * 2 * pi;
coneDirphi = rand(1) * pi;
coneAngle = 45;
N = 1000;
%perfom transformation preventing concentration of points around the pole
rpolar = acos(cos(coneAngle/2*pi/180) + (1-cos(coneAngle/2*pi/180)) * rand(N, 1));
thetapolar = rand(N,1) * 2 * pi;
x0 = rpolar .*  cos(thetapolar);
y0 = rpolar .* sin(thetapolar);

theta = coneDirtheta + x0;
phi = coneDirphi + y0;
r = rand(N, 1);
x = r .* cos(theta) .* sin(phi);
y = r .* sin(theta) .* sin(phi);
z = r .* cos(phi);
scatter3(x,y,z)
```

if all points should be of  length 1 set r = ones(N,1);

Edit:
since intersection of cone with sphere forms a circle first we create random points inside a circle with raduis of (45 / 2) in polar coordinates and as @Ahmed Fasih commented to prevent concentration of points near the pole we should first transform this random points, then convert polar to cartesian 2D coordinates to form x0 and y0

we can use x0 and y0 as phi & theta angle of spherical coordinates and add coneDirtheta & coneDirphi as offsets to these coordinates.
then convert spherical to cartesian 3D coordinates

Comment: Can you explain your solution? The resulting vectors does not form a cone, it is like a "rectangular cone" constrain region.

Comment: @Pedro77 answer updated to form 'circular cone' I added some explanations.

Comment: I think this solution has the same problem that afflicts trying to generate random points on the sphere by uniformly-generating azimuth and elevation (spherical coordinates’ angles): see the first paragraph of http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html — if you use this technique, your solutions will bunch up near the poles.

Comment: @Ahmed Fasih Interesting! Thanks , I edited answer .